# How to stream data (other than audio and video) in quickblox

Tags: quickblox

I would like to stream live data live pixel positions from one Android phone to other. Is it doable using QuickBlox? How to do otherwise?

Thank you

Comment: What is pixel positions ?

Comment: its coordinates of pixel (x,y) that will be changing rapidally. Basically I am trying create a drawing tool on which you can draw at one place and see the drawing in action on some other side

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 1-1 chat for this

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

for example, send new coordinates of pixel (x,y) in each chat message